# Generate shorter public id

Tags: php, hash

I am looking for a way to generate public ids for my objects (like a facebook uid). The id should be unique and the user should not be able to guess it (or the next one).

Right now I am using this:

```
sha1('a fixed random string' . $this->getId())
```

The problem is that sha1 generates very long strings (40 chars) and I would like it to be shorter. I thought about using MD5 but it's known to be not save because you can create collisions. Is this really a problem in my case?

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Hint 1: When there's a collision, you can always append a suffix that gets incremented. Hint 2: Large prime number modulus.

Comment: Are your objects in your database already? Do they have integer IDs? If so, just encode your IDs using [`(new Id())->encode($id)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-IDs) to get unique, random-looking, reversible IDs. Otherwise, generate random strings with something like [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random).

Comment: @caw your comments and actions look like spam. You should make your relations with those projects clear in your comments and profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests to see how long the id will be using different hash functions. I also used [convBase](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base-convert.php#106546) to convert from 0-9a-z to 0-9a-zA-Z as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8428368/956397):

```
$i = mt_rand(1, PHP_INT_MAX);
sha1($i):           40 322c73c44958e4219fd6679aead094192cb672fe
convBase(sha1($i)): 34 1JHrlXObHSVMcbn2bHRBCBIRD3RVKQHMQzg
md5($i):            32 7b09f8cd76be44403b90e971a5a61e6c
convBase(md5($i)):  28 5bgdGpBZekbb3PQlILrSKMtHC24A
$i:                  9 107300785
convBase($i):        5 7gdPP
```

So sha1 is very long even if converted to the other base. Also I am still not sure if MD5 is secure. Anyway, with 28 characters it is still kind of long if you want to post it in an URL on twitter:
http://mydomainsux.com/invite/5bgdGpBZekbb3PQlILrSKMtHC24A

The shortest solution with `convBase($i)` has the problem of not being unique. You would have to check for that manually. Still, I think this is the way to go here because if you use a hash there could also be a natural collusion so you have to check anyway.

I read that you can pre generate the id's in a table and just pick one whenever you need one. This way you do not have to test for uniqueness every time.

Comment: btw: mt_rand is bad for security, use /dev/urandom instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you use strong salt (random string) it is not big problem of MD5 collisions.

Comment: On wikipedia they have an example of a collusion with 1024 bits. I think making it longer does not help if the algorithm is broken. Still, I am not sure if having a collisions is a problem at all in this use case. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to store the ids in a database then you can go for [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). If you're going to use normal id's (those auto_increments) in database and just want to use a representative id create a function with some math calculations inside :)

Comment: uniqid() generates the id based on time and is not secure at all. Maybe it get's better if you are using the $more_entropy parameter...?

Comment: @PiTheNumber, Ehmm, yeah it'd get better but that will be too long (I guess you want something like 10-11 integers). You could generate a prefix and store with prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a random integer and than perform a base convert.
The idea is that you use a target charset of many character such as A-Z, a-z and 0-9. By this your number can be encoded in a very short string.

For the simple version that users 0-9 and a-z you can use the PHP function `base_convert`:
(http://codepad.org/9craDgbt)

```
echo base_convert ( 123456789132465798132 , 10 , 36 );
```

gives you

```
c5m8nqw9ps
```

If you want to have it even shorter, have a look at the function "convBase" in the comments of http://php.net/manual/de/function.base-convert.php. By increasing the number of characters in the target charset, the result gets shorter.

```
convBase($randomInt,'0123456789','0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Comment: convBase is pretty cool to get on a base with upper characters.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you hash unique values like this? I think it's much better to just use the unique integer like it is.

Although, it you really want to hash it, take a look at this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php , that is the complete list of hashing-functions available. Check to see what is installed on your server.

Comment: Because if you page is /invitation/3 and the next one is /invitation/4 you can view all invitations. Yes, I know ACL can solve this but you need user accounts for this but simple I don't want that on this page.

Comment: Nice tip with the algo list. Most of them I did not even know ;) but they are all kind of long or even longer. Still, thanks for your time!