# Convert random values from /dev/urandom

Tags: php, random

As mentioned in the [comments of `mt_rand()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php#105587) it is weak in security and we should use /dev/urandom instead. My problem is that from urandom I get a binary string.

How do I convert this binary string to 0-9a-zA-Z?

Looks like `base_convert()` does not work here.

Comment: Can you give us more background to the problem. There may be a better solution to what you need, like [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) for example.

Comment: why should e.g. base64_encode() not work?

Comment: Well, it does! Just need to convert some chars like =/ But I can't accept you answer here ;)

Comment: ok, there you have it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the record the full function:

```
function randomFromDev($len)
{
    $fp = @fopen('/dev/urandom','rb');
    $result = '';
    if ($fp !== FALSE) {
        $result .= @fread($fp, $len);
        @fclose($fp);
    }
    else
    {
        trigger_error('Can not open /dev/urandom.');
    }
    // convert from binary to string
    $result = base64_encode($result);
    // remove none url chars
    $result = strtr($result, '+/', '-_');
    // Remove = from the end
    $result = str_replace('=', ' ', $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [bin2hex](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) for the binary to string conversion.
And PHP 7 [random_bytes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) added urandom lookup.

```
<?php
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
$str = bin2hex($bytes);
var_dump($str);
// string(10) "385e33f741" 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `base64_encode($yourbinaryurandomstring)`

with that result you can e.g. use a hash function like `sha1()` or `md5()` and should be fine. You don't even have do do any conversion of `"="`

I'm not quite sure if the hash functions can read a binary string for their own, just give it a try.

Comment: Thank you! Naa, no hash function for me today. Just had that [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427999/generate-shorter-public-id/8428368#8428368) ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way of using `/dev/urandom` is the function [uiniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) which should fit your needs.

However, if you need *true random numbers* you should better use `/dev/random` as `/dev/urandom` is still a pseudo random number generator which use `/dev/random` for seed values.

Accessing the random number stream is not that hard.

```
<?php
$r = unpack('v*', fread(fopen('/dev/random', 'r'),16));
$uuid = sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
    $r[1], $r[2], $r[3], $r[4] & 0x0fff | 0x4000, 
    $r[5] & 0x3fff | 0x8000, $r[6], $r[7], $r[8]);
?>
```

Obviously this is not production code.

Comment: A cryptographically-secure PRNG is still useful for crypto. And whether or not `/dev/random` gives you its actual entropy pool depends very much on the OS. In FreeBSD both are the same, using Yarrow.

Comment: Yes I knowed the first part but I don't want to bloat my answer that hard.

Comment: Concerning `uniqid()`: "This function does not create random nor unpredictable strings. This function must not be used for security purposes. Use a cryptographically secure random function/generator and cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure IDs." (from the PHP doc)

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is not pseudo, unlike `rand` or `mt_rand`.  In the worse case it creates random number from a truly random pool which is constantly refreshed.  Most of the time it is exactly as good as `/dev/random`.

Comment: /dev/random is not _more_ random, /dev/random and /dev/urandom  use exactly the same CSPRNG.  

For a  good read see: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/